# I am getting sql server connection error with xampp

Tags: php, sql, sqlsrv

Actually, I followed all the paths in the document, but I still get an undefined sql error while connecting.

I followed these paths respectively.

> 1-Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server® install

> 2-Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server this version: 7.3

dll files in the corresponding folder
**php / ext**

- php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll
- php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll

then I restarted xampp, i viewed phpinfo

[image]

But when I run my file the error I get is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> sqlsrv_connect() in

what could be missing?

Comment: Did you add the `.ddl` into the `php.ini` file ? [Loading Drivers for PHP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Yes, extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll, extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll

Answer (score 1):

You need to [enable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#loading-the-driver-at-php-startup) PHP Driver for SQL Server, but **not** PDO version. Function `sqlsrv_connect()` and all `sqlsrv_` functions are part of the SQLSRV driver.

To enable the SQLSRV driver, you need to modify the `php.ini` by adding the appropriate line to the extension section - `php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll` or `php_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll` depending on the PHP version.

Of course, as an option, you may try to rewrite your code using PDO (PHP Data Objects). The PDPO_SQLSRV part of the driver is installed on your WEB server.